# Using Randomize() before Rnd() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, random

I have previously been told that I should always use `Randomize()` before I use `Rnd()` in a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) application. Yet, it always seems to work fine without it. What does adding `Randomize()` do for me in this case?

It doesn't appear to affect my application in the least.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Basic, [Rnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2.aspx)() uses a mathematical operation to produce the next "random" number. Because the actual operation is known, given a specific value, you can predict the next value. However, given an arbitray start value the numbers have good distribution - these are "pseudo-random" numbers.

To keep `Rnd()` from startng at a predictable number (and hence giving the same sequence of "random" numbers every time), [Randomize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt.aspx)() should be called to use the machine clock to set the initial value (called a seed).

(In the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) world, I'd use [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) instead if you can.)

Answer (score 4):

`Randomize()` initializes the first seed of `Rnd()`. If you won't use it - VB.NET will use the default seed number.

Answer (score 1):

Randomize will set the seed to something time related, like the system uptime or the system date. So the function `Rand()` will show different values every time the app is executed. However, I highly recommend you to use the System.Random class instead of VisualBasic `Rand()`. No need to call any `randomize()` function

Here are some example code, this will generate six random integers from the lower to upper bounds:

```
Dim randObj As New Random( seed )
Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To 5
    Console.Write( "{0,11} ", randObj.Next( lower, upper ) )
Next j
Console.WriteLine( )
```