# How can it get VB not to auto generate code for my component

Tags: vb.net

I build a component class it extends a combo box and generates some random numbers.  But when I drag and drop my component from the toolbox to a form it auto generates Me.Randtest1.Items.AddRange(...) in the Designer which uses static numbers. The idea was to have different numbers each time and not the same.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class randtest
  Inherits ComboBox

  Public Sub New()
    setDefaultText()
    fillComboBox()
  End Sub

  Private Sub setDefaultText()
    Text = Rnd(10)
  End Sub

  Private Sub fillComboBox()

    For count = 0 To 5
      Items.Add(Rnd(10))
    Next

  End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of the constructor:

```
If DesignMode Then Exit Sub
```

That way, it won't generate anything at design time, only at run time.

Just out of curiosity, is this so that the user can pick a random number, or just programatically?

Comment: +1 It also might be a good idea to `Randomize` in there somewhere. Maybe in the `Sub New` or even a static constructer `Shared Sub New` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380990/using-randomize-before-rnd-in-vb-net

Comment: Randomize doesn't really belong in a control. It should go in the form or the Main() function instead.

Comment: This doesn't work, DesignMode isn't yet set to true at constructor time.  Overriding CreateHandle() and adding items if none are present yet is a workaround.