# Random Picturebox Location - VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, random, location

I am making a reaction game that involves the user clicking a picturebox which randomizes its location.

The tricky part is to randomize the picturebox's location so that it appears within the bounds of a panel which i have created. The reason for this is that i have other controls on the form. Not sure if a panel would be the best way of going about this but i am not sure where to start.

The picturebox's size is (70,55) and the panel's size is (640,400) in location (40,69) if it makes any difference.

I have the following code so far:

```
 Dim rnd1 As Integer = panel1.Width * Rnd()
Dim rnd2 As Integer = panel1.Height * Rnd()

pb1.Top = rnd2
pb1.left = rnd1
```

while it works it randomizes the picturebox right on the edges of the panel so that some randomizations result in the picturebox not being visible at all. What code would i have to use so that the picturebox is completely visible and does not cross the bounds of the panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not taking into account the height or width of the PictureBox object.

if you set the left property of the picturebox to be the width of the panel then it will be out of view.

You need to do something like this:

```
Dim rnd1 As Integer = (panel1.Width - pb1.Width) * Rnd()
Dim rnd2 As Integer = (panel1.Height - pb1.Height) * Rnd()

pb1.Top = rnd2
pb1.left = rnd1
```

Note: If you use `Rnd` you need to call `Randmonize()` first otherwise your random numbers will be the same sequence each time you run your application: [Using Randomize() before Rnd() in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380990/using-randomize-before-rnd-in-vb-net)

I would suggest using the `Random` class instead of `Rnd` as this does not require you to initialise a seed before you start using it.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, i will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Use Random class to generate your random number. The argument is the max number you want to generate. For your top location, you generate a number between 0 and the panel's height minus picture box's height. For your left location, a number between 0 and the panel's width minus picture box's width.

Put this in the form declaration.

```
Dim random As New Random
```

Put this in your event (I use a timer event).

```
Dim newTop As Integer = random.Next(panel1.Height - pb1.Height)
Dim newLeft As Integer = random.Next(panel1.Width - pb1.Width)

pb1.Top = newTop
pb1.Left = newLeft
```

Comment: Actually, Matt did suggest using the random class :)

Comment: That's why i also +1'd your answer, but he answered first :( Thanks though. Would you be able to explain the benefits of using random.next opposed to rnd()?

Comment: The Rnd() functions returns a random number between 0 and 1. It's included in the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic and its history comes from older version of VB. Even GW-Basic has Rnd() function. The Rnd() function is useable in VB.Net because normally VB.Net project already includes the namespace. While in C#, you have to manually import the reference and the namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The Random class is a class included in .Net framework. You can use it using any .Net language. The Random class has 3 overloading methods. You can find them in the link below. It returns an integer number between 2 numbers. The first number usually is zero unless you specify a non zero number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.next(v=vs.110).aspx