# How do I calculate the percent chance from using Int(Rnd()) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, random

```
If Int(Rnd() * 5) >= 4
```

The line of code above is supposed to give a 40% chance of something happening. However, I do not understand how this 40% is calculated. Would `Int(Rnd()*2.5) = 1` also give 40%?

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain how calculate percentages using this function.

Comment: [Rnd Function (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y66ey2hh(v=vs.110).aspx) The explanation is at your fingertips via F1

Comment: You should prefer to use [`System.Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) if you can when writing code with the .NET Framework, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1381019/3775798). I think `Rnd()` is kept around as a holdover from legacy Visual Basic code.

Answer (score 2):

`Rnd` returns a number from zero to just less than 1 (in a `Single` data type).

`Int(Rnd() * 5)` would return a value 0 to 4 (indeed 5 distinct values).

So, to give a 40% chance, compare the `result < 2` (0 or 1), or the `result > 2` (3 or 4).

I think you might have been confused by the result being zero-based.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Int` doesn't return a number.  Perhaps you meant `Rnd` in that first sentence?

Comment: Edited, appologies.